# how to use Callback functions from DLL cpp in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to use a DLL written in cpp inside python using ctype. However some errors are visible

I have the code in cpp that I am rewriting a small part in python.

An error is shown when initializing the DLL registration.

C code: https://ideone.com/RLgM5u

```
import os
import sys
from ctypes import *
import ctypes as c
import time

bAtivo = False
bMarketConnected = False

class TAssetID(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ticker", c.c_wchar_p),
        ("bolsa", c.c_wchar_p)]

dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("ProfitDLL")


@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, TAssetID, c.c_wchar_p, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int)
def newTradeCallback(assetId, date,  price, vol, qtd, buyAgent, sellAgent, tradeType):
    print('oi')

@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, TAssetID, c.c_wchar_p, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int)
def newDailyCallback(assetId, date, sOpen, sHigh, sLow, sClose, sVol, sAjuste, sMaxLimit,  sMinLimit, sVolBuyer, sVolSeller, nQtd, nNegocios, nContratosOpen, nQtdBuyer, nQtdSeller, nNegBuyer, nNegSeller):
    print('oi')

@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, TAssetID, c.c_wchar_p, c.c_float, c.c_float, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int)
def newHistoryCallback(assetId, date, price, vol, qtd, buyAgent, sellAgent, tradeType):
    print('oi')

@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, TAssetID, c.c_int)
def progressCallBack(assetId, nProgress):
    print('oi')

@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, TAssetID, c.c_float, c.c_int, c.c_int)
def newTinyBookCallBack(assetId, proce, qtd, side):
    print('oi')

@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, c.c_int, c.c_int)
def stateCallback(nConnStateType, result):

    if nConnStateType == 0: # notificacoes de login
        if result == 0:
            print("(0-0) Login: Conectado.")

        if result == 1:
            print("(0-1) Login: Login invalido.")

        if result == 2:
            print("(0-2) Login: Senha invalida")

        if result == 3:
            print("(0-3) Login: Senha bloqueada")

        if result == 4:
            print("(0-4) Login: Senha expirada")

        if result == 200:
            print("(0-200) Login: Erro desconhecido")

    if nConnStateType == 1: # notificacoes de broker
        if result == 0:
            print("(1-0) Broker: Desconectado.")

        if result == 1:
            print("(1-1) Broker: Connectando")

        if result == 2:
            print("(1-2) Broker: Conectado")

        if result == 3:
            print("(1-3) Broker: Desconectado")

        if result == 4:
            print("(1-4) Broker: Conectando")

        if result == 5:
            print("(1-5) Broker: Conectado")

    if nConnStateType == 2:  # notificacoes de login no Market
        if result == 4:
            print("(2-4) State: Conectado ao Profit")
            time.sleep(3000)
            bMarketConnected = True
        else:
            print("(2-" + result + ") State: Desconectado.")
            bMarketConnected = False

    if nConnStateType == 3: # notificacoes de login no Market
        if result == 0:
            print("(3-0) Atividade: Valida.")
            bAtivo = True
        else:
            print("(3-" +result+ ") Atividade: Invalida.")
            bAtivo = False

    if (nConnStateType == 3 or nConnStateType == 2) and (bAtivo and bMarketConnected):
        dll.SubscribeTicker("WINM20","F")


Code = "d5646546556164654"
keystr = c_wchar_p(Code)


dll.InitializeMarket(keystr, stateCallback, newTradeCallback, newDailyCallback, newHistoryCallback, newTinyBookCallBack)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\aplicationTrader.py",
>   line 104, in 
>       dll.InitializeMarket(keystr, stateCallback, newTradeCallback, newDailyCallback, newHistoryCallback, newTinyBookCallBack) ValueError:
>   Procedure called with not enough arguments (28 bytes missing) or wrong
>   calling convention

I am very grateful for the attention.

Comment: The calling convention is indeed wrong. The C code functions are declared with `__stdcall` so the library must be loaded on Python side with `windll` instead of `cdll`. By the way: The C declaration of the function takes six callback function pointers, not only five.

Comment: Understand. I will change to Win. with respect to function C. Would it be the case that the "keystr" argument is not a function?

 Thanks for listening

Comment: I changed it to windll but another error is shown in bytes - dll = windll.LoadLibrary("ProfitDLL")

Comment: ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing)

Comment: You're missing a parameter.  @MichaelButscher pointed out there are *six* callback functions, not five.  You're missing ProgressCallback.

Comment: I got it Mark Tolonen. Went unnoticed. However it ran and did not print any results. As if I didn't call the functions. Thanks Michael Butscher. Could you help with this one more?

Comment: The callbacks are also `__stdcall`, replace `CFUNCTYPE` by `WINFUNCTYPE` everywhere in the Python code.

Comment: I already did that and it didn't work. I sent you an e-mail. could you help with this?